# Create constant for specifying array size in MATLAB Coder

Tags: matlab, constants, matlab-coder

How can I create a **constant variable** in MATLAB (and its results the generated C code), so I can use it later in my code to specify the size of variables.

I want to have an array that its size is **not hardcoded via number all over** the code. 
I want to specify the size at the beginning of the code like how we do in C code using one of the followings:

```c
const int arraySize=5

#define arraysize 5
```

Later: `int array[arraySize];`

---

When I write the following in MATLAB, Coder just replaces `arraySize` with the actual number which is 5:

```matlab
arraySize=int8(5);
array=zeros(1,arraySize); % zeros is just used for specifying size
```

Generated code:

```c
void coder(double A[5])
{
  memset(&A[0], 0, sizeof(double) << 16);
}
```

---

I tried using the following but it does not allow me to use `arraySize` in MATLAB calculations:

```matlab
arraySize=coder.opaque('const int16','5');
A=zeros(1,arraySize);
```

---

This may be related to **constant folding** which I can not disable!

---

This array size may be repeated throughout the different functions and code many times, so **global** probably may be related to this

Answer (score 3):

Having a constant variable appear by name (rather than the value) in the sizes of other variables is unfortunately not supported in MATLAB Coder as of MATLAB R2019a. We've made an internal note of your request so we can look at lifting that limitation in the future.